# How to exclude multiple file extension from diff target in JGit

Tags: jgit

I found a way to exclude a specified file extension from JGit diff in this way:

```scala
val excludePath = PathSuffixFilter.create(".designer.cs").negate()
val df = new DiffFormatter(DisabledOutputStream.INSTANCE)
df.setPathFilter(excludePath);
```

What should I do for multiple file extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `OrTreeFilter` and an `AndTreeFilter` to combine multiple `TreeFilter`s.

To exclude multiple file endings, combine the single path filters with an `AndTreeFilter` and use this to configure the diff formatter:

```java
val fooFilter = PathSuffixFilter.create(".foo").negate()
val barFilter = PathSuffixFilter.create(".bar").negate()
val treeFilter = AndTreeFilter.create(fooFilter, barFilter);
...
diffFormatter.setPathFilter(treeFilter);
```